# Get return value from python script executed with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a `main.py` that execute `file.py` using `subprocess.Popen`:

```
# Execute request
url = "http://something:50001/dosomething/run"
test = ["python", "file.py", "url", url]
writer = subprocess.Popen(test, shell=False)
```

File.py execute a function that get an "exit code" when it request the url :

```
exitCode = None
answer = requests.get(url)
janswer = answer.json()
exitCode = janswer.get("exitCode")
return exitCode
```

For some reason, I need to execute this `file.py` using `subprocess.Popen` so that some code in `main.py` execute while `file.py` does its stuff.

What I'm trying to do now is to recover the `exitCode` from `file.py` to `main.py`.

I tried to use `stdout=subprocess.Pipe` and recover the exit code with a print, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Getting the `writer.returncode` isn't the solution to because it will give me the code from the subprocess, not from the function
function return `exitCode = -2`, subprocess return `returncode = 0`, I need that -2. (-2 is just an example, the `exitCode` isn't the same all the time and depends on some parameters.)

Comment: Would it be an option to terminate the subprocess using `sys.exit()`? This allows you to specify the exit code of the subprocess, which will then be reflected in `writer.returncode`. Note that the range of values you can return with `sys.exit()` is limited but maybe it is sufficient to use only a few small values.

Comment: that could be usefull for something else, but not right now. I get a code from the url execution, the code is dynamic @DanielJunglas No but thanks for helping buran

Comment: Could you be more explicit why using `stdout = PIPE` does not work? It works fine for me.

Comment: ```stdout = PIPE```, for some obscure reason, send me back the ```url```, not the ```exitCode```, there is no ```print(url)```, just a ```print(exitCode)``` and the ```return exitCode```

Comment: i think the reason why you are not getting the return value is because the subprogram isnt over yet when you try to get the return value. I suggest to use asyc await concept here

Comment: The subprogram is over when I try to get the return value, I double checked it just to be sure, I will check asyc await concept to, more knowledge can't do no harm !

Comment: If you get unexpected output on `stdout` then I think you should debug where this comes from. It does not mean that `PIPE` does not work. It only means that you subprocess outputs more than it should. If you cannot avoid additional output on `stdout` then you could also try to use `stderr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short program that illustrates how you can get a number from a subprocess either via pipe or `sys.exit()`. Note that the range of values that can be returned from `sys.exit()` is limited, though.

```
import sys
import subprocess

def sub():
    try:
        print(42)
    except:
        # Print something even in case of an exception                          
        print(-1)
        raise
    sys.exit(43)

def main():
    writer = subprocess.Popen(["python3", sys.argv[0], "sub"],
                              stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in writer.stdout:
        print(int(line))
    exitcode = writer.wait()
    print('exitcode', exitcode)

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == 'sub':
    sub()
else:
    main()
```

This prints

```
42
exitcode 43
```

Comment: can you try writer.stdout=subprocess.popen.......